# how to use all-or-nothing option for bulksave using node-couchdb-api

Tags: node.js, couchdb

For saving bulk documents i am using bulkDocs function and it is working fine. But how to use all-or-nothing option in bulkDocs function. I have tried the following code.

```
db.bulkDocs(docs, "all-or-nothing",function (err, body, res) {
       console.log(body);
});
```

It's not working for me. Please suggest me to use that option because i need to save all documents or if any error occur none can be saved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [node-couchdb-api](https://github.com/felixge/node-couchdb) `bulkDocs` api only supports two arguments -- data and the callback.  Instead of passing the option as an argument try embedding it in the data passed to `bulkDocs` as shown in the [CouchDB Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API#Transactional_Semantics_with_Bulk_Updates) and below.

For example, I believe this should do what you want but I don't have a system setup at the moment to test it:

```
var data = {
    "all_or_nothing": true,
    "docs": docs
}

db.bulkDocs(data, function(err, body, errs) {
     console.log(body);
}
```

Comment: I tried but i got an error                                            { error: 'unknown_error', reason: 'function_clause' }